# I have to open adminhome1 view when adminhome() function is call

Tags: php, laravel

I have to open adminhome1 view from the controller when the adminhome function is called

this is the function in the controller I tried too many things but didn't work

```
public function adminlogin()
{
        $data = Input::all();
        log::info($data);
        $username = $data['username'];
        $password = $data['password'];
        $query = "call admin_access('$username','$password');";
        $result = DB::select($query);
        $result=count($result);
        log::info($result);
        if($result>0)
        {
            $this->adminhome($username);
        }
        else
        {
          return Response::json('login unsuccessful, please try appropriate username and password',200);
        }
}





  public function adminhome(){   
                log::info('we are in adminhome function');
                //return Redirect::route('/adminhome1');
                //return view('adminhome1');
              //  return Redirect::to('/adminhome1');
                return redirect()->route('adminhome1');
                //return View::make('/adminhome1')->with('name',$username);
              //   return redirect('/adminhome1');
            //   return view('adminhome1')->with('name', 'admin');
        }
```

route data

```
Route::post('/api/adminlogin' , 'demoController@adminlogin');

    Route::any('/adminhome1', function () {
      return view('adminhome1');
  });
```

Comment: Can you tell us what is the result right now? Doesn't work is not enough for us to help.

Comment: stick on same page instead of changing view

Comment: like i have login page if username and password correct then it will redirect to adminhome1 view instead of that its stick with same page

Comment: i tried too many things to chage view as shown in adminhome() function.. none of them is working for me

Comment: `return redirect()->route('adminhome1');` redirects you to a route named `adminhome1`. Your route doesn't have a name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

**demoController**

```
public function adminlogin()
{
    $data = Input::all();
    log::info($data);
    $username = $data['username'];
    $password = $data['password'];
    $query = "call admin_access('$username','$password');";
    $result = DB::select($query);
    $result=count($result);
    log::info($result);
    if($result>0)
    {
        return redirect()->route('adminhome1');
    }
    else
    {
      return Response::json('login unsuccessful, please try appropriate username and password',200);
    }
}




public function adminhome(){   
    return view('adminhome1');
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('/api/adminlogin' , 'demoController@adminlogin')->name('adminlogin');
Route::get('/adminhome1' , 'demoController@adminhome')->name('adminhome1');
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call another function for that

Just do something like this

```
public function adminlogin()
{
        $data = Input::all();
        log::info($data);
        $username = $data['username'];
        $password = $data['password'];
        $query = "call admin_access('$username','$password');";
        $result = DB::select($query);
        $result=count($result);
        log::info($result);
        if($result>0)
        {
            return redirect('adminhome1');
        }
        else
        {
          return Response::json('login unsuccessful, please try appropriate username and password',200);
        }
}

public function adminhome(){   
    log::info('we are in adminhome function');
    return view('adminhome1');
}
```

For the route

```
Route::post('/api/adminlogin' , 'demoController@adminlogin');

Route::any('/adminhome1', 'demoController@adminhome');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```html
public function adminlogin()
{
        $data = Input::all();
        log::info($data);
        $username = $data['username'];
        $password = $data['password'];
        $query = "call admin_access('$username','$password');";
        $result = DB::select($query);
        $result=count($result);
        log::info($result);
        if($result>0)
        {
            // No needed $this->adminhome($username);
            return redirect('/adminhome1');
        }
        else
        {
          return Response::json('login unsuccessful, please try appropriate username and password',200);
        }
}
```

```
Route::any('/adminhome1', function () {
  return view('adminhome1');
```

});